# Why do I find a unique solution of Lorentz and inverse Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity

Lorentz transformation along with inverse Lorentz transformation for 1 spatial dimension are 4 equations containing 4 variables. The equations are:

$x'-\gamma (x-vt)=0$

$t'-\gamma (t-\frac{vx}{c^2})=0$

$x-\gamma (x'+vt')=0$

$t-\gamma (t'+\frac{vx'}{c^2})=0$

And the four variables are $x$, $x'$, $t$ and $t'$. So we have four equations with four variables and so these four equations will have a unique solution. It's evident from the equations that the only solution is $x=x'=t=t'=0$. But shouldn't the equations be valid for all values of the $x,x',t,t'$?

After all we should be able to transform any point in spacetime from one inertial reference frame to another. Then where is my reasoning (terribly) wrong? And what does this obviously wrong solution mean?

Comment: Calculate the determinant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, a little linear algebra tip: $n$ equations in $n$ variables doesn't always have a unique solution. It can have a unique solution or infinitely many solutions. If the equations are linearly independent you get exactly 1 solution. But if the system is linearly dependent you get infinitely many ones.

I'll skip how to check for LI in most general case. However, the main idea of LD is that if you can write an equation in terms of linear combinations of the others, that equation does not introduce new information to the system (so you actually have less than $n$ equations).

In the case of Lorentz transform, you can re-formulate forward and inverse transforms from each other (just try substituting $x'$ and $t'$ into the third equation, you'll end up finding $0=0$, a tautology). This means that these equations are not LI and thus this system of equations has infinitely many solutions.

A final note: Any forward/reverse transform pair is LD since they are designed s.t. you get a tautology when you substitute forward variables in inverse transform or vice versa.

Comment: So there are infinite solutions. But shouldn't these solutions follow some pattern? I can't just plug four random numbers in the equations and expect them to satisfy and the equations.

Comment: @Theoretical Well, in transforms, both the forward and inverse transform are LI in themselves, but then you have e.g. 4 variables with 2 equations. The "solution space" of this system isn't $\mathbb R^4$ but a 2-dimensional subspace of it. Though visualizing/interpreting this is not that easy without some knowledge and practice in linear algebra. If you don't have that, I urge you to look up or listen to some stuff about that.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument shows correctly that (in $1+1$ dimensions) a Lorentz transformation fixes only the origin.

You seem to be disturbed by the fact that spacetime should be homogeneous, so the group of transformations should act transitively (i.e. you ought to be able to map the origin to any other event you want to, because all events are essentially "the same").

The resolution is that the group of structure-preserving maps of spacetime is not just the Lorentz group; instead it is generated by the Lorentz group **plus translations**.

So for example, the map $x\mapsto x+1$, $t\mapsto t+2$ preserves the structure of spacetime but is not a Lorentz transformation.

If two observers choose the same point to call the origin, their coordinate systems will differ by a Lorentz transformation.  If they choose different origins, their coordinate systems will differ by a Lorentz transformation plus a translation.